# Google Colab Syntax Error: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, haversine

I found out python library '[haversine](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/)', used to calculate distance between 2 geometry coordinates. I put a comment in Google Colab Jupyter Notebook and run 'pip install haversine' like below.

Surprisingly, I got a 'Syntax Error'. I remove the comment and the command run successfully.
What is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well to install any library in google colab you need to put an exclamation mark before statement like following;

```
!pip install haversine
```

Comment: TQ @Divyessh, it works. Just another silly question for newbie in Google Colab. Why `pip install <package name>` works without comment within the cell?

Comment: please give an example of such a package @OngK.S

Comment: for my case, `pip install haversine` works without comment. I tried `pip install memory_profiler` and get the same error.

Comment: well it might have to do something with already installed packages because in my general practice, I have always used the exclamation mark or percentage sign. So sorry I dont know about it

Comment: no worry @Divyessh, you already help a lot. I will take your advice.

Comment: Thanks! After adding the exclamation mark I was able to run pip install successfully in my Colab file.